# react hook useEffect to fetch data on button click (typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a component and I want to fetch isbn data on button click using react hook useEffect, performing a `get` on the route `${basicUrl}/editorials/${isbn}`, so i wrote this component:

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import { V3_BASIC_URL } from "../../constants/endpoints";
import { useDataApi } from "../../store/effects/dataEffects";

import SearchIsbnElement from "../../components/SearchIsbnElement/SearchIsbnElement";
import IsbnPanelElement from "../../components/IsbnPanelElement/IsbnPanelElement";

function Home() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<string>("9788808677853");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const url = `${V3_BASIC_URL(
    process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENV
  )}/editorials/${query}`;
  const [{ isbn, isLoading, isError }, doFetch] = useDataApi(url, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    isbn: undefined,
  });

  const buttonCallback = () => {
    doFetch(url);
  };
  const isbnRegexp = /^97\d{11}$/
  const validateQuery = (query: string): boolean => isbnRegexp.test(query)

  const inputCallback = (query: string) => {
    setQuery(query)
    setIsValid(validateQuery(query));
  };

  return (
    <div id="isbn-panel-home" className="Home">
      <SearchIsbnElement
        inputCallback={inputCallback}
        buttonCallback={buttonCallback}
        query={query}
        isValid={isValid}
      ></SearchIsbnElement>
      {isError && <div>Il servizio al momento non è disponibile, riprova più tardi</div>}
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading ...</div>
      ) : (
        !isError && 
        <Fragment>
          <IsbnPanelElement isbn={isbn}></IsbnPanelElement> 
          <p>{isbn?.scheda_volume == null && 'isbn non trovato'}</p>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

the `useDataApi` function uses the hook useEffect and returns `state` and `setUrl` action to set the new url on isbn value change. This is the `useDataApi` file:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

import {
  dataFetchFailure,
  dataFetchInit,
  dataFetchSuccess,
} from "../actions/dataActions";
import { dataFetchReducer, ISBNState } from "../reducers/dataReducers";
import { get } from "../../tools/request";

type InitialState = {
  isLoading: boolean,
  isError: boolean,
  isbn: undefined,
}

export const useDataApi = (initialUrl: string, initialData: InitialState) : [ISBNState, (value: string) => void]  => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel: boolean = false;

    const fetchData = async (): Promise<any> => {
      dispatch(dataFetchInit());
      const options = {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        auth: {
          username: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_USER}`,
          password: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_PWD}`
        }
      }
      try {
        const {data} = await get(url, options);
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch(dataFetchSuccess(data));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch(dataFetchFailure(error));
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  return [state, setUrl];
};
```

with this code fetching starts on page load, but i want to fetch data only on button click. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useEffect() is a hook to manipulate the component through the different lifecycle methods. In order to do something onClick you need to create a method for that:

```
const fetchData = async (): Promise<any> => {
  dispatch(dataFetchInit());
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    auth: {
      username: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_USER}`,
      password: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_PWD}`
    }
  }
  try {
    const {data} = await get(url, options);
    if (!didCancel) {
      dispatch(dataFetchSuccess(data));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (!didCancel) {
      dispatch(dataFetchFailure(error));
    }
  }
};
```

Just do that and you will be fine

Edit: the new version of `useDataApi`

```js
export const useDataApi = (
  url: string,
  initialData: InitialState
): [ISBNState, (value: string) => void] => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, initialData);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async (): Promise<any> => {
    dispatch(dataFetchInit());
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      auth: {
        username: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_USER}`,
        password: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_PWD}`,
      },
    };
    try {
      const { data } = await get(url, options);
      dispatch(dataFetchSuccess(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(dataFetchFailure(error));
    }
  }, [url]);

  return [state, fetchData];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `useDataApi` hook returns `[,doFetch]`, but the `doFetch` is actually `setUrl` so if you wanted that to work as expected you can let the initial value for the url be null or falsey and only allow a fetch inside the effect when the url is valid/truthy. When you click the button, thats when you setUrl and that's when the effect will allow a `fetchData` to occur because by then the value of `url` will be set.

```
export const useDataApi = (initialUrl: string, initialData: InitialState): [ISBNState, (value: string) => void] => {
  // make this default to null here, or where you intende to use this hook 
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  // custom hook body

  useEffect(() => {
    // effect body
    if (url) {
      fetchData();
    }
    // hook cleanup
  }, [url]);

  return [state, setUrl];
};
```

Although, the better solution is directly calling the function `fetchData` on the button click. One way you can do that is by modifying your `useDataApi` hook to return 'fetchData' directly allowing it to accept the `url` as an argument and removing the need for the `const [url,setUrl] = useState(initialUrl)` entirely

```
export const useDataApi = (initialUrl: string, initialData: InitialState): [ISBNState, (value: string) => void] => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, initialData);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async (url): Promise<any> => {
    dispatch(dataFetchInit());
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_USER}`,
        password: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH_PWD}`,
      },
    };
    try {
      const { data } = await get(url, options);
      if (!didCancel) {
        dispatch(dataFetchSuccess(data));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!didCancel) {
        dispatch(dataFetchFailure(error));
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return [state, fetchData];
};
```

You can also drop `initialUrl` from the hook `useDataApi`

Comment: If I change the `initialUrl` to `url` since I do not initialUrl anymore, I don't need to use url param in fetchData. I need to set the missing dependency `url` in useCallback too

Comment: For the second code snippet i added, you don't need to add `url` to the callback, its not a dependency in that one because the url is coming from the function's argument.